# Why do perl dancer pages render slowly (while I'm not connected to internet)?

Tags: perl, dancer

I'm running [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/) and found it slow -- pages took a long time to render.

This is the example code from [Dancer::Introduction](http://p3rl.org/Dancer::Introduction):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# make this script a webapp
use Dancer;
# declare routes/actions
get '/' => sub {
    "Hello World";
};
get '/hello/:name' => sub {
    "Hello ".param('name');
};
# run the webserver
Dancer->dance;
```

It takes my browser 10 seconds to get&render the response( using firebug in firefox ).

And [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/) message:

```
[20734]  core @0.000228> request: GET / from 192.168.1.101 in /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Dancer/Handler.pm l. 57
[20734]  core @0.000809> [hit #44]trying to match `/' against /^\/$/ in /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Dancer/Route.pm l. 84
[20734]  core @0.000953> [hit #44]  --> got 1 in /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Dancer/Route.pm l. 101
[20734]  core @0.001645> [hit #44]response: 200 in /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Dancer/Handler.pm l. 175
[20734]  core @0.000135> request: GET /favicon.ico from 192.168.1.101 in /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Dancer/Handler.pm l. 57
[20734]  core @0.000873> [hit #45]response: 200 in /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Dancer/Handler.pm l. 175
```

Why is [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/) so slow? Did I miss something?

Comment: What's your command-line argument to start the application server?

Comment: perl dancer.pl #dancer.pl stored above code

Comment: I'm guessing you have a config file since core messages don't show up by default. Care to share any remaining details?

Comment: I dont change anything after `dancer -a testapp`. config.yml: appname: "testapp" layout: "main" charset: "UTF-8" template: "simple" 
environments/development.yml: logger: "console" log: "core"  warnings: 1 show_errors: 1 auto_reload: 0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is the computer connected to internet? I got the same problem when testing from a computer not connected to internet; fixed it by deleting

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>;
```

from `main.tt`

Comment: er... this makes sense to anyone?

Comment: Browser pauses to attempt resolving ajax.googleapis.com, waits, waits, times out.  Firebug or similar client side tools would have revealed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the debugging log, it took Dancer 0.6ms to serve the request. The problem is somewhere else in the stack. A frequent culprit is reverse DNS — the webserver tries to reverse-lookup the remote IP address for access logging purposes, and if your DNS is misconfigured, that can take quite a while (sometimes 30 or 60 seconds) before it fails.

Comment: How to disable DNS reverse-lookup ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Dancer::Plugin::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/module/Dancer%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aNYTProf) to profile your application. From the documentation:

> By simply loading this plugin, you'll have the detailed, helpful
>   profiling provided by Devel::NYTProf.
>
> Each individual request to your app is profiled. Going to the URL
>   **/nytprof** in your app will present a list of profiles.

Or, if it's a browser-side issue, you can use an extension like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see what part of a page load is slow.

Comment: The problem was a javascript cdn request while offline. I don't think this would have helped as its necessarily a browser behavior. Plus the solution was posted years ago.

Comment: @Joel I have added a Firebug link. The idea is to never assume - if someone else finds the question, but an answer is different, he should know how to profile both perl- and browser-side.

Comment: ok, with that, I have un-downvoted. The open question of "Is SO for the OP or the future reader?" is one that waves back and forth; with both answers you walk the narrow line.